How to import materialX into blender 4.1
Comming from this post:
How to import MaterialX library into blender?
But since I can't comment, I would like to ask the same question again.
For my surprise, I couldn't find any addon, or updated content on that topic. I know about Hydra Storm renderer, but yet, how one can simply import a MaterialX without a USD file?

heading for my new tumbleweed badge ;o;
